# Passing WPF user control selection to host control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a WPF user control with a list box. I want to pass the selected item in the list box to the calling control through binding. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean passing it to the parent control in which your user control resides? Are you using MVVM? How are you populating your list box? Please provide as much details as possible and some code(xaml in your usercontrol) will make it easy to provide correct answer to you.

Comment: Yes, hopefully you are using some form of MVVM or presentation model variant, so you can bind your user control list box SelectedItem to a property on the model, which is then exposed to your parent control (which in tern binds to it).

Answer (score 1):

You can expose a new property for SelectedItem on your user control and bind it to the child control ListBox.

Code for your user control (I inherited from Control though):

```
public class CustomListControl : Control
{
    static CustomListControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomListControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomListControl)));

        SelectedItemProperty = ListBox.SelectedItemProperty.AddOwner(typeof(CustomListControl));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty;

    public Object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And add the binding from the inner ListBox to your UserControl in the Generic.xaml markup:

```
<ListBox
    SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomListControl},Mode=FindAncestor},Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
</ListBox>
```